# IPython Notebook - Detect if Kernel is Busy/Idle in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ipython

I'm currently trying to get interactive plots working with IPython notebook. One of the issues I'm having is the fact that when executing Python code through the IPython.notebook.kernel.execute method in javascript I have no way of knowing when that piece of code has finished executing. Is there an easy way of detecting whether the kernel is busy/idle so that I can tell Javascript to idle until it's completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kernel status is probably what you are looking for:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/messaging.html#kernel-status

You can find some additional inspiration in the kernel.js of the IPython notebook (just search for "busy"):

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/static/js/kernel.js

Comment: This seems to have moved when the project was split and rejuggled. I see it here:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/services/kernels/kernel.js

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but just in case anyone is looking...

```
    require(['base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function (IPython, events) {
        events.on('kernel_idle.Kernel', yourFunction);
    });
```

Comment: ... where is this documented?

Comment: Never found any docs on the JavaScript side.  The best place to look is the code.