# Jupyter / iPython notebook - Kernel Busy when input() is called

Tags: azure, kernel, jupyter-notebook

When a simple task is performed:

```
a = input("Input:")
```

I get the Kernel Busy: In[*].

Some times, I **Interrupt** and **Restart & Clear Output** and it works, some times not.
I know that I am not able to make the input() work two times in a row.

This happens in my Jupyter notebook running at my computer and also running at Azure Notebook.

Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: look at the following links https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513797/5255006, http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/messaging.html#kernel-status

Comment: Not sure what I must look for at those links... as far as I understood it is at the DEALER of the Kernel the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have a similar problem and have found no solution so far. Are you only trying to call this code? Is there other code in the cell?

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters long time, i don't know how I did it. How is your solution? Probably there were more code in the cell (at least the try, and except).

Comment: For me, the `input()` function seems to cause the kernel to hang only when called in a loop. I haven't tried many other scenarios yet.